# How to record time in Postgresql via sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I absolutely do not understand how to write the net time to the database.

I create a table via sqlalchemy using the time object. Am I doing everything right?

```
windows = Table(
    "windows", meta,
    Column("courier_id", Integer, ForeignKey("couriers.courier_id"), nullable=False),
    Column("start_time", Time),
    Column("end_time", Time)
)
```

And how do I upload the data now? I did it like this

```
query = datab.windows.insert().values([1, 09:00, 18:00])
            await conn.execute(query)
```

Аnd there is one more question. How to specify which columns to fill in in insert()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `datetime.time()` object to specify the time values and pass the `.values()` as a dict with the column names as the keys:

```py
import datetime 

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Table,
    Column,
    Integer,
    Time,
    ForeignKey,
    MetaData,
)

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)

windows = Table(
    "windows",
    MetaData(),
    Column(
        "courier_id",
        Integer,
        # ForeignKey("couriers.courier_id"),  # omit for this example
        nullable=False,
    ),
    Column("start_time", Time),
    Column("end_time", Time),
)
windows.create(engine)

stmt = windows.insert().values(
    {
        "courier_id": 1,
        "start_time": datetime.time(9),
        "end_time": datetime.time(18),
    }
)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(stmt)
"""SQL generated:
2021-03-24 16:57:50,811 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2021-03-24 16:57:50,813 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO windows (courier_id, start_time, end_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
2021-03-24 16:57:50,813 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00036s] (1, '09:00:00.000000', '18:00:00.000000')
2021-03-24 16:57:50,813 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
"""
```

Comment: I was given this error: asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $2: datetime.time(18, 0) (expected a datetime.date or datetime.datetime instance, got 'time')

Comment: What database backend are you using? Does it support time-only columns?

Comment: I use postgresql and the asyncpgsa library

Comment: The above code also works fine using `postgresql://…` with vanilla SQLAlchemy. Are you working with an existing table? If so, then check the "start_time" and "end_time" columns to see if they are really defined as `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

Comment: The table exists, I work with the standard Sqlalchemy and the columns are defined correctly. I tend to think that the asyncpgsa library doesn't have a time format. Thanks for the help